# Zend Framework specific module session configuration

Tags: session, zend-framework, configuration, bootstrapping

I'm trying to get a different session configuration for 2 modules.

In my application ini i have a modules set up like :

```
resources.modules[] =
resources.frontcontroller.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules" 
resources.frontcontroller.throwerrors     = true 
resources.layout.layout                   = "layout"
```

and for the sessions

```
resources.session.save_path           = APPLICATION_PATH "/temp/session"
resources.session.use_cookies         = true
resources.session.use_only_cookies    = true
resources.session.gc_maxlifetime      = 3600
resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 3600
resources.session.name                = "sid"
resources.session.gc_probability      = 1


backoffice.resources.session.save_path           = APPLICATION_PATH "/temp/bo/session"
backoffice.resources.session.use_cookies         = true
backoffice.resources.session.use_only_cookies    = true
backoffice.resources.session.gc_maxlifetime      = 3600
backoffice.resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 3600
backoffice.resources.session.name                = "BOsid"
backoffice.resources.session.gc_probability      = 1
```

but when i go the backoffice module i still have my default configuraton

Any idea what should be the best way to get different sessions for different modules ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I want to advise you another method of config customization for specific modules in ZF:
1. Create for each module config file: `/modules/$moduleName/configs/module.ini`
2. Add to the root Bootstrap the next code:

```
protected function _initBootstrap()
{
    $_conf = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . "/modules/" . $this->getModuleName() . "/configs/module.ini", APPLICATION_ENV);
    $this->_options = array_merge($this->_options, $_conf->toArray()); 

}
```

Comment: Thanks but there is no method getModuleName() in the bootstrap object

Answer (score 0):

I finally opted for a controller plug-in.

With some code like

```
class App_Controller_Plugin_Session extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{


public function routeShutdown(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{
$config = Zend_Registry::get('config')->toArray();


if( $this->getRequest()->getModuleName() == 'backoffice'   ) {
  $conf = $config['sessionBackoffice'];
} else {
  $conf = $config['sessionDefault'];
}


Zend_Session::setOptions($conf);
Zend_Session::start();

}
}
```

The plugin need to be added at first in the registerPlugin stack if you some other plugin that require sessions.

If you have a better solution i'm open.

Comment: To use Controller Plugins for this is absolutely fine. http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/234-Module-Bootstraps-in-Zend-Framework-Dos-and-Donts.html for further information.

Comment: Thanks for the insteresting reading. If the Zend guys says that Plugins are the best way so far , i guess it is.